# Safest key for mcrypt 128 bit key?

Tags: php

What is the safest key for mcrypt?

What does it mean to use a 128 bit key? How many characters is that?

My key is 32 chars with numbers and letters.

I'm using mcrypt to encrypt/decrypt personal data of users signed to my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as the *safest* key. It is like a "password".
The key gives allows you to encode/decode data if the encoding algorithm is symmetric.

A 128bit key is just a key composed of 128 bits which is 16 bytes.
In ASCII, 1 byte = 1 character; but most keys are just random binary data, which can be base64-encoded leading to a string representation of 24 characters.

Besides, [mcrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php) is a php extension which enables you to use several encoding algorithms using the same interface. The size of the key, depends on the algorithm.
See [mcrypt_module_get_algo_key_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-module-get-algo-key-size.php) for the size of the key for a selected algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The safest key is just a bunch of random data (binary is pretty good), and yes a 128 bit key uses 32 characters. A nonce function should suffice to create a strong key (and hashing it can help if you are paranoid):

```
function nonce($l = 32, $raw = true){
    $ret = '';
    for($x = 0; $x < $l; $x++) $ret .= chr(mt_rand(0,255));
    return ($raw ? $ret : base64_encode($ret));
}
```

A pretty strong hash function would be like this (This hash function is a PBKDF2 hash):

```
function hash($p, $s, $c = 5000, $kl = null, $a = 'SHA256'){
    $hl = strlen(hash($a, null, true));
    if(is_null($kl)) $kl = $hl;
    $kb = ceil($kl/$hl);
    $dk = '';
    for($block = 1; $block <= $kb; $block++){
        $ib = $b = hash_hmac($a, $s.pack('N', $block), $p, true);
        for($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++)
            $ib ^= ($b = hash_hmac($a, $b, $p, true));
        $dk .= $ib;
    }
    return substr($dk, 0, $kl);
}
```

And you would use it like this:

```
$key = hash(nonce(), nonce(), 5000, 32);
```